# Is quantum deletion via a partial randomization procedure possible?

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-operation

The paper, [Quantum deletion is possible via a partial randomization procedure](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0007035) claims that it is possible to bypass the no-deleting theorem by a procedure called R-deletion. But this seems to go against the [original no-deleting theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9911090). If not, why so?

And doesn't the following line from the first paper actually convey a swapping operation which has been categorically excluded by Pati and Braunstein?

> But, whatever this state be in our actual realization of R-deletion, we do not recover now, from the linearity of Quantum Mechanics, the result in {1} that $|A_\psi\rangle= \alpha|A_H\rangle +\beta|A_V\rangle$.